# Audio Plays A Second Time When Going Back To Menu Unity

Tags: unity, audio

I am trying to have my background music keep playing in between scenes, but the music just plays another copy of itself instead of destroying itself to let only one copy play at a time. This is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static MusicManager instance;

    void Awake() {
        if (instance != null && instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); 
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing right/wrong so any help is appreciated.

Edit: I found something that works

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static MusicManager instance = null;
    private static MusicManager Instance {
        get {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake() {
        if (instance != null && instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        } else {
            instance = this;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); 
    }
}
```

This thread can be closed now.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem, you should post it as an Answer below, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This works

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static MusicManager instance = null;
    private static MusicManager Instance {
        get {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake() {
        if (instance != null && instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        } else {
            instance = this;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); 
    }
}
```
````